# sed -i not working in php shell_exec()

Tags: php, apache, bash, sed, shell-exec

I'd like to be able to remotely remove/add development banners using shell_exec() in a php file. The sed -i function is not working when run from php/apache. SELINUX is disabled. Running test.sh from terminal as another user works just fine. Browser returns the following:

```
    Reset/Set Environments

    Running now...
    /sbin/nologin
    sed is /bin/sed
    sed: couldn't open temporary file /var/www/html/folder/folder/folderwithoutwritepermission/sed63Klhk: Permission denied
    EOF
```

Here's the code:

PHP File:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Reset/Set Environments</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
</head> 
<body> 

<h1>Reset/Set Environments</h1>

<?php

$output = shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/pages/test.sh');
echo("<pre>{$output}</pre>");

?>

</body> 
</html>
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/html/pages/;

echo "Running now...";

echo $SHELL;

type -a sed;

find -L /var/www/html/ -name 'template.php' 2>&1 | xargs sed -i 's/<body>/<body><div style=\"position: fixed; padding: 14px; background-color: #00ff00; width:100%; opacity: 0.5;\"><span style=\"color: #009900; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;\">DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT<\/span><\/div>/g' 2>&1

echo "EOF";
```

Comment: Try adding a `2>&1` to the end of the `sed` call so you can see STDERR - `shell_exec()` and friends only pipe STDOUT by default. My first thought is permissions somewhere, maybe that `/home/myusername/projectpath/` is not writable by the user PHP is running as.

Comment: Depending on your OS, `sh` may actually be some completely different shell. e.g. on Ubuntu it's really `dash`. Shebangs are ignored when you feed a script directly to a shell, so you're not running this as a bash script, you're running this as whatever shell your `sh` really is.

Comment: @MarcB Not sure I follow you there, are you saying you could work around this with an explicit `/bin/bash /var/www/html/pages/test.sh`

Comment: Yes. instead of `shell_exec('sh ...')`, try `shell_exec('/bin/bash ...')`.

Comment: @MarcB does the shebang not force bash?

Comment: @jpiasetz: Only if you run the script directly from the command line, e.g. `$ ./script.sh`. Otherwise it's just a comment.

Comment: Updated. The issue has something to do with one of the directories that doesn't have write permissions. Just assume I have good reasons that I can't give that directory write permission. Any way I can get sed to ignore the issue and continue on? As it is now, there are about 20 template.php files, and none of them add the banner. However, if I give that one directory write permissions, then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the user account apache is running under has it's shell set to `/bin/nologin`

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-shell-restricting-access.html

Comment: Not the problem. The issue lies somewhere with user (apache) not having write permissions to a certain directory.

Comment: why not su to the user that apache is running under and try running the script?